# How to come up with a workable solution to read a dip chart from user inputs?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My plan is to develop a mobile app which reads a dip chart (fuel dip chart in this case). [image: Sample]

What happens is this: I have an EditText, and a Button called calculate, user enters any number in editText and click the button. Let us say the user enters digit 1 and clicks the button, according to the sample dip chart linked, 1 = 12037, so when user enters 1 and clicks the button I want a toast message to show result 12037. When user enters 2, Toast shows 34001, when user enters 10, toast shows 376079. All these results are according to dip chart.

My question is: How best can I implement this in an easier way. Um sure there is a way, but I have no Idea where to start from. Any suggestions?